# Wordpress loop order

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need to order the following wordpress loop by a custom field. Where can i set the order in this loop?

```
<?php 
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

<?php
while ($query->have_posts())
{
$query->the_post();
?>

// THE CONTENT 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you need to write your own `WP_QUERY`, based on the sortable fields, passing by `$args` in WP_QUERY.. see more for [WP_QUERY](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will use the get_posts function to load all the ‘events’ posts ordered by a custom field value of ‘start_date’.

```
<?php 

// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'start_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));

if( $posts ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

        setup_postdata( $post )

        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> (date: <?php the_field('start_date'); ?>)</a>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

refer https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the order by passing args on `WP_Query`. For meta

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
'meta_key'   => 'age',
'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
'order'      => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'age',
        'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ),
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for more details.